# How to debug python tests with vimspector?

Tags: python, debugging, vim, pytest, vimspector

#### Sample code

**main.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = "hello, world"
    print(test)
```

**sometest.py**

```
import pytest

def test_something():
    print("running da test...")
    foo = 42
    assert foo==42
    assert 1==2
```

**.vimspector.json**

```
{
    "configurations": {
        "main":{
            "adapter": "debugpy",
            "configuration": {
                "name": "run the executable",
                "type": "python",
                "request": "launch",
                "python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3",
                "program": "~/p/pydebugtest/main.py"
            }
        },
        "test":{
            "adapter": "debugpy",
            "configuration": {
                "name": "run the test",
                "module": "unittest",
                "type": "python",
                "request": "launch",
                "python": "pytest",
                "args": [
                  "-q",
                  "${Test}"
                ]

            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Problem

Probably, the `test` configuration in `.vimspector.json` is wrong, because I cannot start the debugging session in Vim. This is what happens:

1. Go to line 4 in `sometest.py`
2. `:call vimspector#ToggleBreakpoint()`
3. `:call vimspector#Launch()`
4. Prompt asks "Which launch configuration?", type `2`
5. Prompt asks "Enter value for Test", type `sometest.py`
6. After some time, the following error message appears:

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════X
║ Initialize for session test (0) Failed ║
║                                        ║
║ Timeout                                ║
║                                        ║
║ Use :VimspectorReset to close          ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

And the following message in the status bar:

`Protocol error: duplicate response for request 1`

#### Question

What would be the right way to configure Vimspector so that I can debug the sample test within Vim?

#### Remarks

1.) Running the test from the terminal works fine:

```
$ pytest -q sometest.py                                                                                                               
F                                                                                                                                     [100%]
================================================================= FAILURES ==================================================================
______________________________________________________________ test_something _______________________________________________________________

    def test_something():
        print("running da test...")
        foo = 42
        assert foo==42
>       assert 1==2
E       assert 1 == 2

sometest.py:7: AssertionError
----------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call ------------------------------------------------------------
running da test...
========================================================== short test summary info ==========================================================
FAILED sometest.py::test_something - assert 1 == 2
1 failed in 0.06s
```

2.) Debugging `main.py` works fine as well with the following steps:

1. Go to line 4
2. `:call vimspector#ToggleBreakpoint()`
3. `:call vimspector#Launch()`
4. Prompt asks "Which launch configuration?", type `1`
5. Type default answers for the handling of exceptions.
6. At this point, Vimspector opens and stops at line 4 as expected.

3.) In case that matters, I can provide the relevant Vim configuration (`vim --version`), but I believe it is not important, given that I can debug the main program with Vimspector, so it must be an issue with the json configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make the sample from above work (and added some other improvements, like defaults for treating exceptions, and taking the currently open test file name). Leaving it here for anyone else that has the same issue:

**.vimspector.json**

```
{
    "configurations": {
        "main":{
            "adapter": "debugpy",
            "configuration": {
                "name": "run the executable",
                "type": "python",
                "request": "launch",
                "python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3",
                "program": "~/p/pydebugtest/main.py"
            },
            "breakpoints": {
                "exception": {
                  "raised": "N",
                  "caught": "N",
                  "uncaught": "Y",
                  "userUnhandled": "N"
                }
            }
        },
        "test":{
            "adapter": "debugpy",
            "configuration": {
                "name": "run the test",
                "module": "pytest",
                "type": "python",
                "request": "launch",
                "python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3",
                "args": [
                  "-q",
                  "${file}"
                ]

            },
            "breakpoints": {
                "exception": {
                  "raised": "N",
                  "caught": "N",
                  "uncaught": "Y",
                  "userUnhandled": "N"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```